# Insertar datos de dos tablas al mismo tiempo en un jFrame

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statements

Estoy tratando de insertar datos de dos tablas relacionadas, tabla `CLIENTES` y tabla `CONTACTO_EMERGENCIA`, al mismo tiempo, por medio de un `JFrame` en NetBeans. Este `JFrame` contiene un botón <kbd>aceptar</kbd> y, hasta ahora, solo logro hacer que inserte los datos de la tabla `CLIENTES`, pero aún no logro hacer que, mediante ese mismo botón, inserte los datos de la tabla `CONTACTO_EMERGENCIA` (cabe destacar que esto lo estoy haciendo en un único `JFrame`, el cual contiene dos paneles que piden datos específicos, un panel para cada tabla).

Estoy haciendo la base de datos en MySQL.

He buscado tutoriales y leído información en varios foros, pero realmente no resuelven mi problema, sería de gran ayuda si alguien pudiera resolver mi duda.

Corrigiendo algo que me han mencionado en los comentarios, en este código solo incluí la sentencia necesaria para insertar datos en la tabla CLIENTES, puesto que aún no averiguaba la forma de insertarlos en la tabla CONTACTO_EMERGENCIA (:

Aquí el código del botón "Aceptar".

---

```
Connection conexion=null;

try{
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Clientes (Nombre, Apellido, Sexo, Edad, Telefono, Peso) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, txtNombre.getText() );
    ps.setString(2, txtApellidos.getText() ); 
    ps.setString(3, comboBoxSexo.getSelectedItem().toString() );
    ps.setString(4, txtEdad.getText() );
    ps.setString(5, txtTelefono.getText() );
    ps.setString(6, txtPeso.getText() );


    int res = ps.executeUpdate();

    if (res>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PERSONA GUARDADA");
    } else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FALLA AL GUARDAR");

    }//fin else
    conexion.close(); //cerrando la conexión

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}//Fin TryCath
limpiarCaja(); //Limpia el texto introducido
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas Rocio10, en el código solo veo que intentas insertar en la tabla `clientes`.

Comment: La manera más óptima de hacerlo sería crear un Procedimiento Almacenado en la base de datos. Sin embargo, también podrías usar una query en la que llames el método de bd "select last_insert_id()"; con esto obtendrías el último id insertado y con eso podrías crear la segunda sentencia necesaria para la segunda tabla.

Comment: Hola Cristhian, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, verificaré la opción que me diste con el last_insert_id(), ya que por lo que he investigado sí me será muy útil obtener wl último id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien comentan arriba, el código que nos has pasado es solo un `INSERT` para la tabla de `clientes`, con lo cual para la tabla de `contacto_emergencia` no estás haciendo nada.
Si dices que al pulsar sobre el boton aceptar cogerá los datos de los dos paneles, simplemente tienes que hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
Connection conexion=null;

try{
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Clientes (Nombre, Apellido, Sexo, Edad, Telefono, Peso) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, txtNombre.getText() );
    ps.setString(2, txtApellidos.getText() ); 
    ps.setString(3, comboBoxSexo.getSelectedItem().toString() );
    ps.setString(4, txtEdad.getText() );
    ps.setString(5, txtTelefono.getText() );
    ps.setString(6, txtPeso.getText() );


    int res = ps.executeUpdate();

    if (res>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PERSONA GUARDADA");
    } else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FALLA AL GUARDAR");
    }

     ps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO contacto_emergencia(Id_cliente, Nombre_contacto, Telefono_contacto) VALUES ((select MAX(Id) from clientes,?,?)");

     ps.setString(1, txtNombreContactoEmergencia.getText());
     ps.setString(2, txtTelefonoContactoEmergencia.getText());

     res = ps.executeUpdate();

    if (res>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CONTACTO DE EMERGENCIA GUARDADO");
    } else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FALLA AL GUARDAR");
    }

    }//fin else
    conexion.close(); //cerrando la conexión

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}//Fin TryCath
limpiarCaja(); //Limpia el texto introducido
```

Me he aventurado a poner el nombre de los textbox que cogería los datos para esa tabla, cuando copies, cámbialos a los que tengas tu. Aparte de que he imaginado que los Id de la tabla `cliente` es un numerico autoincremental.

Comment: Hola Valentín, gracias por tu correción en el código, he estado buscando la forma de incluír la sentencia en el mismo jframe y esta es la respuesta que estaba buscando para eso c: ah, y sí, efectivamente, solo incluí la primer tabla en el código, porque todavía no encontraba la forma de hacer que se insertara la información en la otra tabla. Ahora sé una alternativa. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta 